# What is the better way (CSS or JQuery) of doing it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added the screenshot below, Here I have a link which is on bottom left by default. There is a container above it, which has some width which changes when I resize my window. I can get this link on the right place using "Margin-left", or "Padding-left" or "Left", "Bottom" properties of CSS. But it changes when I resize my window. I will have to write media queries for all the resolutions separately. Is there any other better way of doing it for which I don't have to add much media queries.

I mean any way to automatically detect the position of container and place it below it?

**EDIT**: Please open the image in new tab to see properly.

[image: here is the screenshot.]

Comment: You can/should look into how Twitter Bootstrap has done this with `class="col-md-3"` =)

Comment: Aside from being an interesting question, this unfortunately does not fit the scope of StackOverflow because quite frankly you are not showing any useful/substantial HTML or CSS and are asking for an opinion.

Comment: better way is CSS as it's doable in CSS and that keeps it more accessible. jQuery is overkill for just laying out things like this I think

Answer (score 2):

add same container and include your links in the container and check.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="your links wapper">
    <!--your links here-->
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: how is the progress ?

Comment: it is working but as I am using the same class, it is giving the container box as well.
(This container is bxslider <http://bxslider.com/>)

Answer (score 2):

If the container has a fixed height you could use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` on the link. Otherwise you could wrap the current container in a `div`, then have it like:

```
<div id='new-conteiner'>
  <div id='original-container'>...(container stuff)</div>
  <div id='my-link'>... <a href='...'>blah blah link text blah</a></div>
</div>
```

This assumes that the original container displays as a block, and its sibling div also displays as block. If you have any resizing going on you'll probably have to apply this to the new container.

The link should then always be below your original container element.